# Export array of objects each containing array of objects in a attribute in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

My data structure is like this:

```
Contents = [];
class Post:
  def __init__(self, poster,poster_url,post_text, post_images, post_comments):
    self.poster = poster
    self.poster_url = poster_url
    self.post_text = post_text
    self.post_images = post_images
    self.post_comments = post_comments    

class Comment:
  def __init__(self, poster,poster_url,post_text, post_images):
    self.poster = poster
    self.poster_url = poster_url
    self.post_text = post_text
    self.post_images = post_images
```

I am trying to store array of comment inside post class and post class inside array Contents.But I am not finding any way to export this.How should I export this to formats like csv,excel or json?

Comment: what issue are you facing? and what did you try to do?

Comment: what is the array of class? i only see a `dict` objects nested in the list.

Comment: also, please check that it is a valid py code above.

Comment: I have added a picture.please have a look.I need to export the Contents array

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Post updated with codes.Please have a look now